# I want the design like freecharge

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android. I want to create a design like the freelancer android app, in which half screen is of a different color and other half is of different color. How can i divide the screen exact to half just like that dynamically. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi Shalu, I would suggest posting your code or something you have tried to receive helpful answers. The SO Tour will help you understand how to increase your chances of getting an answer http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

In you activity xml use main linear layout and provide weightsum attribute 2 and privide height matchparent and also set orientation vertical.in this main layout create 2 more layouts and provide layout weight 1 to both.so it will create exactly 2 parth of your screen.